# How to ensure Just My Code is stepped into when debugging Javascript in NODE environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, debugging

Given: Node.js console application (using Visual Studio) which has downloaded several packages via NPM.  When NPM does this it downloads the source code of those packages and puts them into the node modules folder.

Problem: The javascript code that I'm writing needs debugging of which I will often single step into to see the code paths.  But the problem is it defines "Just My Code" as being anything it used during the "compile" of the project.  This includes those node modules so I wind up on long goose chases often.

Is there a way to exclude single stepping into the node modules and in effect only step into "just my code"...?

Comment: I think this might be a better question to ask on the GitHub repo for NTVS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that VS2015 code debugger code itself must do this.  NTVS hasn't done it yet, and the MSFT team knows this is an issue.  When they fix it I'll post back.

Comment: The issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/225